# Eclipse with Cordova 3.6.4 under Android 4.4.2. - the new CordovaApp-CordovaLib project library

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

To convert some Cordova V2 Android applications to Cordova 3.6.4 under Android 4.4.2, I built a skeleton project using the CLI, e.g.

```
cordova create DirProject1 com.example.project1 Project1

cd DirProject1

cordova platform add android

cordova build
```

followed by Eclipse / Import / Android / Existing Android Code into Workspace

The automatic creation of the supplementary CordovaApp-CordovaLib project was a surprise, but the reasons for it are understandable.

The project installed and displayed fine in AVD. So far so good.

Before populating this skeleton project with code and settings from one of the old Cordova applications, I tried copying the project using Copy / Paste to create a second skeleton project. Whoops! Android SDK got half ways through the Paste and crashed with a Java null pointer exception.

As a workaround, I created a second skeleton project (Project2) in the same way as the first one. But when I came to Import into Eclipse, the CordovaApp-CordovaLib project was marked as not importable as it was already in the workspace. No surprise there.

But the imported Project 2 was marked faulty because its Android Dependencies has no `cordovaapp-cordovalib.jar`.  I tried to add the `cordovaapp-cordovalib.jar` from the first project via Configure Build Path / Libraries. Project still hosed.

So I went into Project Properties / Android and added a link to the first project’s `cordovaapp-cordovalib.jar` into the Libraries section (which already had a CordovaLib entry with a big red X by it).

This worked, but is a poor fudge since Project 2 and later ones all depend on the existence of Project 1 and its libraries.

Q: DAK how Cordova projects built in Eclipse using the new CordovaApp-CordovaLib project mechanism (apart from the first one in a workspace) are supposed to resolve links to `cordovalib.jar`?